# How can I lock my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, synthesizer

I have a roland d-20. Is there anyway I can lock it so you need a password or combination of keys to unlock it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. But you could take the power cord with you when you leave it.

Comment: This made me smile :)

Comment: Heh - http://www.seacoastonline.com/articles/20110504-NEWS-110509918